# Active SF Open Source application

Tags: developer, developer-edition, developer-org

I was wondering if there is any active open-source SF project to which you can contribute and learn.

I saw only one, [NPSP](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP) but it seems to be closed for us to contribute since there is no helping guide about how to install it from the source.

Comment: This question is very broad and might be voted closed by the community, but I think there's value to our site if we keep it and would like to post a community wiki answer. I'll let the voters have the final word.

Answer (score 3):

### Open Source Projects

Note that not all projects may be under active development, and the contribution process may differ broadly between repositories.

Prospective contributors should review the project, look for open issues and/or a contributing guide, and consider reaching out to project maintainers if they identify a feature or issue on which they'd like to contribute.

- [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (3-clause BSD License)
- [fflib Apex Commons](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common) (3-clause BSD License)
- [Apex Domain Builder](https://github.com/rsoesemann/apex-domainbuilder) (MIT License)
- [Apex Unified Logging](https://github.com/rsoesemann/apex-unified-logging) (MIT License)
- [Salesforce Test Factory](https://github.com/dhoechst/Salesforce-Test-Factory)
- [Salesforce Limit Monitor](https://github.com/dhoechst/salesforce-limit-monitor)
- Some material from [Unofficial SF](https://unofficialsf.com/) is open source on GitHub, e.g., [Lightning Flow Components](https://github.com/alexed1/LightningFlowComponents)

#### Off-Platform Open Source Projects

- [simple_salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) Python API library (Apache License)
- [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) JavaScript API library (MIT License)
- [HappySoup.io](https://github.com/pgonzaleznetwork/sfdc-happy-soup) package building tool (MIT License)

Answer (score 2):

*Disclosure: I am an employee of Salesforce.org and am involved in many of the projects mentioned below. All projects mentioned are free and open source.*

### Salesforce.org Open Source Projects

Salesforce.org maintains a number of open source projects targeting the nonprofit and education sectors:

- The [Nonprofit Success Pack](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP) is not closed to contributions. It is an open source project licensed under the [BSD License](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP/blob/master/LICENSE). You're right, however, that the contributing documentation is out of date and not well surfaced. See below for one possible entry point.
- The [Education Data Architecture](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/EDA)
- The [K-12 Architecture Kit](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/k12-architecture-kit), which extends EDA.
- The [Program Management Module](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/PMM), which is usable both independently and with NPSP.
- The [Outbound Funds Module](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/OutboundFunds), which is usable both independently and with NPSP.

These products are all maintained by Salesforce.org engineering staff. They're open source under the BSD License, and you certainly could build a contribution for them if you wish.

#### Open Source Commons

The Open Source Commons program, also run by Salesforce.org, supports open source managed packages targeting the nonprofit and educational sphere. OSC projects are originated and run by members of the community, with infrastructure support from Salesforce.org staff. They are built in part through SFDO's Community Sprint program.

- [Group on Trailblazer Community](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F94S000000GwVK)
- [Documentation](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/SFDO-OSC-Get-Started)
- [GitHub Organization](https://github.com/SFDO-Community-Sprints)

#### CumulusCI Toolchain

Salesforce.org's open source projects are developed using CumulusCI, which is introduced in [this sequence of Trailhead modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-applications-with-cumulusci). Once you're up to speed on CumulusCI, developing on NPSP or EDA works much like any other project using that toolchain, although of course some projects have unique frameworks, like the TDTM Table Driven Trigger Management framework, and have specific expectations about test coverage, performance, bulkification, and so on.

There are numerous other open source Salesforce projects in the community, covered in a separate answer.